# Call REST service from Apache Camel Blueprint

Tags: json, rest, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi, cxfrs

I want to call external REST service that return a JSON, the REST itself have a basic authentication (which I don't know how to send a basic authentication), I've read some tutorial and also CXFRS component that lead me to this `blueprint.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

  <bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider"/>

  <cxf:rsClient id="rsClient" address="http://localhost/test.php">
    <cxf:providers>
      <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
    </cxf:providers>
  </cxf:rsClient>

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <propertyPlaceholder location="classpath:sql.properties" id="placeholder"/>

    <route>
      <from uri="cxfrs://bean://rsClient"/>
      <log message="${body}"/>
    </route>

  </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

If it's even relevant, I'm using JBoss Developer Studio to develop and to test  using right click on `blueprint.xml -> Run As -> Local Camel Context (without tests)` here is output from that.

```
[ERROR] *************************************
[ERROR] Error occurred while running main from: org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main
[ERROR] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$1.run(RunMojo.java:488)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Gave up waiting for service (objectClass=org.apache.camel.CamelContext)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:265)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:226)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main.doStart(Main.java:110)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:150)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:354)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main.main(Main.java:84)
    ... 6 more
[ERROR] *************************************
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:07 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-04T12:11:28+07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/314M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1.redhat-621084:run (default-cli) on project dsource: null: MojoExecutionException: InvocationTargetException: Gave up waiting for service (objectClass=org.apache.camel.CamelContext) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Apart the error I got, how exactly I can call or invoke REST service from Apache Camel using Blueprint and get the returned JSON?

Comment: I would think it is far easier to use the rest dsl to simple rest operations. See here:
http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html . Also, any reason you are using the red hat version?

Comment: Is Rest DSL actually just to define or create REST server service? not consume or invoke external REST service? Because the company I work put RedHat JBoss as the requirement of our integration. Oh by the way, while looking at Rest DSL there is `camel-jetty`, can I use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this, but using Camel HTTP component, I can easily call REST API and get the JSON response, but first I have to set some header before.

```
<route>
  <from uri="timer:foo?repeatCount=1"/>

  <setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_METHOD">
    <constant>GET</constant>
  </setHeader>

  <to uri="http:localhost/api/test"/>
  <log message="${body}"/>
</route>
```